# Does FriendCaster have problems with the privacy settings of my friends?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I am fed up with the official Facebook application and want to switch. FriendCaster seems to be one of the very good choices. However I saw in reviews and other websites that FriendCaster will not show everything in the news feed because it might not have access to my friend's information due to privacy settings.

Is this true?

Would I not see everything with FriendCaster which I would have seen in the official Facebook app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a privacy setting that will prevent FriendCaster from being able to retrieve posts or other info from your friends if they have it enabled. Specifically, according to [OneLouder's support site](http://support.onelouder.com/entries/20289163-missing-posts-or-friends-in-friendcaster):

> [I]t is possible that some of your friends have set their privacy
>   settings to block access to their profile, wall, photos and status
>   updates from third party apps like FriendCaster.  This setting is
>   found in "Account --> Privacy Settings --> Apps and Websites".
>
> In “Info accessible through your friends” you can see checkboxes for
>   the items that are available to apps.  As an example, If your friend
>   has “My Photos” unchecked here, they won’t appear in FriendCaster.
>
> Unfortunately Facebook has this restriction in place and unless your
>   friend allows third party apps we can't get around it at this time. If
>   your friends are using that setting, the info will only appear on
>   Facebook itself.